# How can I make a SearchRequest in ES 6.0 from a json string using High level REST Client in Scala

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm migrating from ES 1.7 to 6.0 and I'm trying to figure out a way to perform a search request passing a plain query to the [High Level REST Java client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/6.x/java-rest-high-search.html). To keep queries easy to read (and maintain), we want to use a Json string instead of building them with the SearchSourceBuilder. This was possible before but I'm not finding a nice way to do it now.

Example query:

```
 {
    "filter": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "status": "Success"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "type": "someType"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "range": {
                        "endDateTime": {
                            "lte": "someDateTime"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Example code:

```
val searchRequest = buildSearchRequest(indexName, indexType, query)
val searchResponse = restHighLevelClient.search(searchRequest)
```

I know it's possible to send the query using the LowLevelClient but it returns a Response and not a SearchResponse. Has anyone faced this issue before? Any workaround or solution?

Comment: very good question!!

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. How did you solve it?

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little bit late, but I have a close solution for your problem.

Firstly, you need to build your query with something like this:

```
private QueryBuilder buildQuery(MyObject object) {
    BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();

    QueryBuilder statusTerm = QueryBuilders.termQuery("status", object.getStatus());
    QueryBuilder typeTerm = QueryBuilders.termQuery("type", object.getType());
    QueryBuilder boolQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
            .must(statusTerm)
            .must(typeTerm);
    queryBuilder.should(boolQuery);

    return queryBuilder;
}
```

Then, you can perform your search and return `SearchResponse`:

```
private SearchResponse search(QueryBuilder query) throws IOException {

    SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest(elasticSearchClient.getElasticsearchClientProperties().getIndices());

    SearchSourceBuilder searchRequestBuilder = request.source();
    searchRequestBuilder.query(query);

    //SearchSourcebuilder allows you to set your query into your request

    return this.elasticSearchClient.search(request);
}
```

Finally, can have a method that calls both:

```
public void processSearch(MyObject object) {
    QueryBuilder query = buildQuery(object);
    SearchResponse response = search(query);
    List<FoundObjects> objects = parseResponse(response);
}
```

I hope this could help. Good luck!